# Issue on Adding a div to Requierd Place Using .after() and .insertAfter() Methods

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add an eeror message div after a class  in jQuery using after() method.

My original HTML code is like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"> Name</span>
      <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Za-z ]+" autofocus="" required="" placeholder="Your Name">
</div>
```

and I am using this jquery code

```
$('.input-group :input[required]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val()==='') {
    $(this).after('<div class="err">This is a Requierd Field</div>');
}
```

after running the code the `.err` div been added to page but inside the `.input-group` but I need the add it **After** that class (`.input-group`). Here is the source code:
[image]

I also tried to use the jQuery `.insertAfter()` method as :

```
$('<div class="err">This is a Required Field</div>').insertAfter('.input-group');
```

it inserted the div `.err` in required place , HOWEVER it is duplicating the div based on `.each()` function! for example if I have three inputs it loop three times for three element!

Can you please let me know how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `parent()` or `closest()`

```
 $('.input-group :input[required]').each(function() {
   var $this=$(this);
   if ($this.val()==='') {
       $this.parent().after('<div class="err">This is a Requierd Field</div>');
   }
 });
```

or

```
 $(this).closest('.input-group').after('<div class="err">This is a Requierd Field</div>');
```